# Why does my <div> have the shakes? onmouseleave event firing when over an element

Tags: javascript, css, html

I recently created a javascript library that adds tilt to an element based on the cursor position over the element.  When I just apply this to a div it works great!

```
<div id="profile-image" class="circle-base large-image" title=""></div>
```

However, when inside another div it starts to flicker.

```
<div id="home" class="large-circle-container pull-right">
<div class="circle-base large-circle"></div>
<a href="/">
<div id="profile-image" class="circle-base large-image" title=""></div>
</a>
</div>
```

[Here is a my in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andywarr/QVWbh/2/).

I have identified that the cause of the flicker is the "home" div.  I am unsure why though.  Looking at the console it seems the styles for onmouseleave are being applied when the cursor is over the element.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`tilty` should have been negated, not `tiltx`

```
tiltx = (dy / cy);
tilty = -(dx / cx);
```

Issue resolved!